# Jdbc connection with Informix from databricks

Tags: jdbc, databricks, informix

I want to run query on Informix database from Databricks.
Earlier when my application was running on Linux, I have extracted data from Informix by setting up client sdk and used dbaccess and other tools.
However, I don't understand how to setup a databricks instance to run queries against Informix database.
In Databricks, i can import any pypi/maven or other libraries. However i cannot setup client sdk tools like that was possible on a linux environment.

Few of the ways i have looked at are:

1. IfxPy and it needs a Client SDK, which i dont seem to translate into databricks world as its not a linux environment.
2. ibm_db - I tried this and was not able to make to connect to informix DB. it supports only drda protocol.

Any pointers on how to setup the environment?

Comment: You would have to configure the Informix instance to have a DRDA listener — but then the IBM driver should work.  That's a question of configuring a new server alias with the appropriate protocol (I think that would be `drsoctcp`, but check the docs).  I don't know enough about the DataBricks environment to know what might be involved with using CSDK more directly.

Comment: Zero experience with Databricks, but looking at `https://docs.databricks.com/external-data/jdbc.html` it appears it should allow you to use just JDBC to connect to an informix database.
Is not that what you want?

Comment: i will check on the usage of `drsoctcp`. I am using JDBC connection as mentioned on databricks site. Its quite possible that i might be missing network or a misplaced identifiers of the Informix DB.

Comment: if you use the Informix JDBC driver there is will be no need to setup a DRDA listener. 
Check the connection string, if it starts with `jdbc:ids://localhost:9092`  is the DRDA JDBC driver, if starts with `jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:9089` is the SQLI one (Informix JDBC driver)

Comment: With JDBC Driver, i used general port number.
jdbc:informix-sqli://<<DB_HOST>>:<<PORT>>/<<DB_INSTANCE>>:USER=USER_NAME;PASSWORD=<<PWD>>;DELIMIDENT=Y;IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT=5;IFX_ISOLATION_LEVEL=1

With ibm_db packages, i had to use a drda port on the database listner. 
DATABASE=<<DB_INSTANCE>>;HOSTNAME=<<HOSTNAME>>;PORT=<<DRDA_PORTNUMBER>>;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=<<USER_NAME>>;PWD=<<PASSWORD>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JDBC Driver, i used general port number.

```
jdbc:informix-sqli://<<DB_HOST>>:<<PORT>>/<<DB_INSTANCE>>:USER=USER_NAME;PASSWORD=<<PWD>>;DELIMIDENT=Y;IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT=5;IFX_ISOLATION_LEVEL=1
```

With ibm_db packages, i had to use a drda port on the database listner.

```
DATABASE=<<DB_INSTANCE>>;HOSTNAME=<<HOSTNAME>>;PORT=<<DRDA_PORTNUMBER>>;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=<<USER_NAME>>;PWD=<<PASSWORD>
```